# ruby do map and compact together

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby and this looks wrong but works fine

```
def get_internal_deps
  self.internal_dependencies = self.sources.map do |f| 
    s = File.open(File.join(self.dir, f)).grep(/\d{8}-\w{5}/)
    if s.length > 0
      {:file => f, :line => s}
    end
  end.compact
  #how crazy does that look?
end
```

So how do I do this without having an `end.compact`?

Comment: Is `internal_dependencies` an instance variable?

Comment: can `s` have more than one line?

Comment: you can also replace `do end` with curly braces. I also think that `end.some_method` looks weird

Comment: @cobaltsoda: In Ruby, instance variables start with an `@` sigil, so it cannot possibly be an instance variable. It could theoretically be either a local variable or a receiverless message send without an argument list. Which of the two it is depends on whether an assignment to a local variable of that name has been parsed before the line in question. But note that `internal_dependencies` does not actually appear in the OP's code. There is only a message send to the `internal_dependencies=` method.

Comment: I know how instance variables work. I was asking *specifically for this question* if `@internal_dependencies` has been defined elsewhere.

Comment: I have` attr_accessor :internal_dependencies` on the class which I think creates an instance variable.

Comment: and yes there can be more than one line. Without the `compact` it creates empty array entries for all the files that don't have a match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Some notes

- Your method is called `get_internal_deps`, but it looks like it actually sets an instance variable.
- You could define `internal_dependencies` and use caching.
- In this case, you'd need to remove any `attr_reader/writer/accessor` for `@internal_dependencies`.
- `File.open(f)` isn't really clean.
- You don't need `self` in `self.dir` or `self.sources`
- `:line` is an Array. Shouldn't it be called :lines?
- 2 separate, short methods might be better than a bigger one.

## Refactored code

```
def internal_dependencies
  @internal_dependencies ||= sources.map{|s| parse_dependency(s) }
                                    .reject{|h| h[:line].empty? }
end

private

def parse_dependency(source)
  {
    file: source,
    line: File.readlines(File.join(dir, source)).grep(/\d{8}-\w{5}/)
  }
end
```

Comment: You could `return @internal_dependencies if defined? @internal_dependencies` at the start of the method, and then use `each` to build the array all in one loop (instead of `.map.reject`). Apart from that, great answer.

Comment: @cobaltsoda: Thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure I understand what the advantage would be, though. I usually prefer chaining specialized Enumerable methods instead of usung `each`, as long as it doesn't result in more iterations.

Comment: Sorry, hard to explain over a comment box. I meant something like `@internal_dependencies = []; sources.each { |s| p = parse_dependency(s); @internal_dependencies << p if p[:line] }; @internal_dependencies`, which iterates over each item once, whereas `.map.reject` iterates over each item twice.

Comment: Thanks. I guess it's a matter of taste. BTW, you call `parse_dependency` twice ;)

Comment: It would only really benefit if there were a large amount of dependencies, I just like nit-picking.

Comment: Even then, I'm not sure it would make much of a difference. Reading and parsing a file will always be much slower than looking up a value in a Hash.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid `compact` one might use `reduce` ([`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) in this particular case) instead of `map`:

```
def get_internal_deps
  self.internal_dependencies = sources.each_with_object do |f, acc|
    s = File.open(File.join(self.dir, f)).grep(/\d{8}-\w{5}/)
    acc << {:file => f, :line => s} if s.length > 0
  end
end
```

Also, note that an explicit `self` receiver might make sense in a case of assignment, but it is completely redundant in RHO (`sources` in this snippet.)